# Convert matrix elements from decimal to binary

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal

I have a matrix with decimal elements. I want to convert every element in this matrix to binary with a resolution of 8. What function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dec2bin`:

```
>> dec2bin([10; 100; 255], 8)

ans =

00001010
01100100
11111111
```

The second parameter tells it to use at least N bits (where `N==8` here).

Comment: i had a function that wrote the values in a specified format: element1,element2,..... element2: 'fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d,\n', 1, numel(IND_B) - 1),'%d;\r\n'], IND_B.');'
How should i modify this function to print an 8 bit element after another exactly as in the previous format?

Comment: sorry for the writing. I didn't found out how to wrap code on this forum yet

Comment: Note that of course the output of [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) is actually a string (class `char`) not actual bits.

Comment: I noticed that. So how can I write the 8 bits elements in the format specified?I tried %c but it writes 1 bit per element.

Comment: Actually it writes one element as 8 elements separated by ","

Comment: How about just `'%s'` - a string?